# Display not auto rotating on Miix 320

Tags: gnome, screen, tablet, orientation

I installed ubuntu 21.04 on my Lenovo Miix 320 (a tablet notebook hybrid).
While running Ubuntu from the USB Stick in the installation mode the Screen turned automatically but after installing it it does not.

Can anyone tell me what I have to do or what I did wrong?